# NFS noac does not force synchronisation

Tags: nfs, synchronization

I am running a cluster. The home directories are mounted using NFS.

The following gives an error on the cluster:

```
node-a$ ssh node-b touch /home/user/testFile && rm /home/user/testFile
rm: cannot remove `/home/user/testFile': No such file or directory
```

However, the following works:

```
node-a$ ssh node-b touch /home/user/testFile && ls /home/user && rm /home/user/
```

I have already activated mount options `sync,noac`. Could this be a bug in either the linux kernel (which is `2.6.33.1` on this clustering system) or in the embedded linux of the NAS providing the NFS share ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And apparently, it is a bug in the Firmware version `3.1.14.995 2011-09-09 15:35` of the `Iomega StorCenter px4-300r` NAS appliance. With another NFS server, this works correctly.

Move on, nothing to see here...